# ¿Como optimizar proceso en php o ejecutarlo en segundo plano?

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo en php que se encarga de cerrar la sesión pero antes debe de cambiar el estatus en varias bases de datos diferentes, este proceso tarda un poco, por lo que el navegador se queda esperando y hasta que termina redirige a index.php
Este es el código  para cerrar la sesión...

```
      <?php
      include 'HistorialController.php';
      include_once 'clases/Sistemas.php';
      session_start();

      $_SESSION['login'] = false;
      $_SESSION['recordar'] = 'no';         

      $liberar = new Sistemas('');
      $liberar->libera();

      unset($_SESSION['login']);
      header('Location: index.php');    
      ?>
```

El código de liberar es la siguiente...

```
       /**
       * Metodo que Libera las imagenes ocupadas por el usuario al salir de la session
       **/
       public function libera(){
           $id_user = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
           $actualiza = "UPDATE Imagen SET estatuspm_web=0 WHERE id_usuariopm_web=" . $id_user." and estatuspm_web=1";
           for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->listaSistemas); $i++){ //RECORRIDO DE LOS SISTEMAS 
                $sistemaActual = $this->listaSistemas[$i];                 
                $baseConn = new BaseConexion("Sistema_".$sistemaActual); 
                if ($conn = $baseConn->conectar()) {
                     sqlsrv_query( $conn, $actualiza, $params);                      
                }
                $baseConn->close();
            }
       }
```

Comment: Si tu proceso va a tardar, te recomendaría usar un modal de carga, para hacer ver al usuario que la web está cargando. De todas maneras, si haces ver al usuario que ha cerrado sesión, y aún no se ha completado lo que quieres hacer en segundo plano, si el usuario cierra la web, se cargaría todo tu proceso, por lo que no tendría sentido hacer ver al usuario que ya ha cerrado sesión y está todo bien.

Comment: @cnbandicoot tienes razón, no me había planteado lo del cierre del navegador... ¿No estoy seguro, pero si un proceso se empieza a ejecutar del lado del servidor, y al cerrar el navegador, este proceso se interrumpe?

Comment: Si de alguna manera se pudiera ejecutar el proceso de `libera()` en segundo plano, y responder de inmediato que la sesión terminó, en realidad el proceso PHP seguiría corriendo hasta completar su misión. Es casi como decirle: "cierra el browser si quieres, nosotros seguiremos haciendo algunas cosas en el backend pero no es tu problema". 
PD: si alguien contesta esta pregunta con `react/event-loop` será mi ídolo por siempre.

Comment: es necesario que este proceso corra a nivel de cliente? podría correr como un cronjob? rapidamente se me ocurre que podrías hacer que este proceso no cierre TODO de una sola vez, sino que vaya cerrando de a poco, mediante varias llamadas. avisame por acá y te dejo una respuesta sobre como hacerlo

Comment: @amenadiel he tratado de hacer cosas con `react/event-loop` pero es como ponerle herraduras a un perro y meterlo a hacer hípica: PHP no fue pensado para eso, mejor usar herramientas que si lo están (i.e.: nodejs, ruby, jvm, go <3)

Comment: @Pablo Alcantar lo único que necesito es que no se quede esperando, es decir si el usuario le da al boton salir y confirma que quiere salir, que no tarde tanto en mostrar index.php que es la pagina inicial de logueo.

Comment: Pablo, lo malo de eso es que dado que estás en un PHP, para correr algo en node se vuelve aparatoso. Por ejemplo se puede hacer con un request asíncrono de guzzle, que por debajo ocupa una promesa.

Comment: Hay otra posibilidad, que es hacer la petición por ajax y en determinado momento abortar el request. El front se libera y php sigue corriendo. De elegante no tiene nada, pero funciona.

Comment: y que pasa si creo otro archivo php donde hago la llamada de `libera()` y ejecuto este php con `exec('controladores/miArchivo.php')` con esto se hace rápido pero no se que hace internamente.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se desloguea, guardar en una tabla `cierres_de_sesion` el `id_usuario` y tener un cronjob que tome una a una las filas de esta tabla y ejecute asincrona la lógica de liberacion. Según veo, la lista de sistemas es dependiente del usuario, así que funcionaría bastante bien.

Pros: Quitas este trabajo de cerrar sesiones del proceso de logout y lo dejas como una tarea externa, por lo que puedes redirijir a index.php de inmediato.
Contras: Si tienes MUCHOS clientes cerrando sesion al mismo tiempo, tendrías que hacer alguna lógica de paralelización (y por ende sincronización) para que estos jobs corran eficientemente y no se te acumule mucho trabajo. Podrías usar una cola de trabajo o algo así, pero posiblemente complique mucho el sistema.